# how to get input value in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

could you please tell me how to get `input field` value or in other words username and password  input field value on button click .

here is my code
https://rnplay.org/apps/drT9vw

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  registerComponent,
} from 'react-native-playground';
import {
      Text,
    View,
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    TextInput,
    TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            userName :'',
            password:''
        };
    }

    login(){
        alert(this.state.userName)
    }
    OnChangesValue(e){
        console.log(e.nativeEvent.text);
        this.setState({
            userName :e.nativeEvent.text,
        })
    }

    changePassword(e){
        console.log(e.nativeEvent.text);
        this.setState({
            password :e.nativeEvent.text,
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

                <Text style={styles.heading}> Login</Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.loginInput}
                    onChange={(text)=> this.setState({userName:text})}
                    ref="myInput"
                    underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                    placeholder="username !"
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.loginInput}
                    ref="pass"
                    onChange={this.changePassword.bind(this)}
                    underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                    placeholder="password to ff!"
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                />
                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.touchable} onPress={this.login.bind(this)}>
                    <Text style={styles.touchableButton}>Click</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>

        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#EF501E',
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding :20
    },
    logo: {
        width: 50,
        height: 50
    },
    heading: {
        fontSize: 30,
        marginTop: 20
    },
    loginInput: {
        height: 50,
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#33090C',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginBottom:10
    },
    touchable:{
        backgroundColor:'#2E18DD',
        height:40,
        alignSelf:'stretch',
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center'

    },
    touchableButton:{
      color:'#fff',
        fontSize:10
    }
});

registerComponent(App);
```

**update**

```
login(){
        alert(this.refs.myInput.value)
    }
```

it give undefined

Answer (score 1):

Not getting the exact issue, u are storing the userName and password in state variable. So you can get the values the by `this.state.userName` and `this.state.password`. or u can use the refs also to get the value like this: `this.refs.myInput.value`.

Change this fun:

```
changePassword(text){
    console.log(text);
    this.setState({
        password :text,
    })
}
```

Check the same example on tutorialspoint: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_text_input.htm

Comment: refs will not work, because ur textinput does not have a value property, use state. it will work.

Comment: is there any problem when u are using `this.state.userName` and `this.state.pass` ?

Comment: see https://rnplay.org/apps/drT9vw it gives object when I try to get username on button click

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in two ways. If the input fields are controlled, you can get the values from  the state itself. In case of uncontrolled input fields (your case), you can use [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to get the input values

```
login() {
    console.log(this.refs.myInput.value)
}
```

Comment: On clicking the button the alert shows the string which was typed in the username input box. What's undefined ?